# IBM Mobilefirst: Invoke adapter from a java file under server/java folder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Is it possible to invoke an adapter from a java file, like the equivalent for `WL.server.invokeProcedure` in the javascript.

Please suggest other ways if thats not an option.

Comment: What Java code are you referring to? Are you talking about Java code that's part of an adapter, or Java code running on another machine/server?

Comment: As part of the same work light project, say the file is inside server/java folder.I understand invoking java in another machine, but please ignore that.

Comment: @Futur, can you explain again? Do you have a regular adapter (implemented in JavaScript) that you would like to invoke from Java code stored in server\java?

Comment: @IdanAdar Thats exactly what I'm looking at.

Comment: You can see the example in the PDF from Worklight 6.2: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_12_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf --- it was removed because the code contained errors, but it should be possible to correct that. It is a starting point.

Comment: @IdanAdar Thats correct, please share your answer below, I will mark it. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the example in the PDF from Worklight 6.2: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_12_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf

The code example may contain errors there so you'll probably need to adjust it.
However if Leandro's example helped you progress further and implement the correct code - you should go with his answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the pdf pointed in the comment from Idan, a sample of code to do what you need is the following:

```
public JSONObject invokeProcedure(String adapterName, String procedureName, String parameterArray){
    //parameterArray should be in format "['param1','param2','param3']
    DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService(); 
    ProcedureQName procedureQName = new ProcedureQName(adapterName, procedureName);
    InvocationResult result = service.invokeProcedure(procedureQName, parameterArray);
    JSONObject jsonObject = result.toJSON();
    return jsonObject;
}
```